# Scale on click animation

Tags: javascript

Tread sofly, I've just started and couldn't find a similar problem... at least what I think would be the solution ;)

So I've got a robot written in HTML and CSS and I want to animate its lips on click. The idea is to make it like a kiss shape, so I need to scale it to a tiny size(1) and then put it back to normal (2). For now I don't really know how to do it. I tried just changing the width and height size but it didn't work. My guess is I need to do something with the transfort scaleX and scaleY but no idea what and how.

This is what I've already got:

```
var lips = document.getElementById("lips");
lips.addEventListener("click", kiss);

function kiss(e) {
    var partRobo = e.target;
    var sizeX= 1;
    var sizeY= 1;
    
    var id = setInterval(action, 20);
    
    function action() {
        partRobo.style.transform = scale(sizeX, sizeY);
        sizeX-0.1;
        sizeY-0.1;
        
        if (sizeX === 0 && sizeY=== 0) {
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add/remove classes and set your transformation in your CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, and here is one of them

```js
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function () {
  this.style.transform = "scale(1.2)";
  setTimeout(()=>{
     this.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  },500)
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0, 2.28, 0.95, 0.69) 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is my fav. Unfortunately I can't vote you guys up yet. But thanks all of you ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation), JS would be needed only for triggering the animation. Of course you can change the duration, easing function and other params of the animation.

```css
#lips {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.kiss {
  animation: kiss 4s;
}

@keyframes kiss {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="lips" onclick="this.classList.add('kiss')"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to do something purely in JS to learn but your tips are a learning experience, too - just in another way ^^

Answer (score 0):

I would make a css rule along the lines of

```
.lips-kiss {
    transform: scale(0.6);
}
```

and then in the function `kiss`, apply and remove the class. So your code would look like,

```
var lips = document.getElementById("lips");
lips.addEventListener("click", kiss);

function kiss() {
    lips.classList.add('lips-kiss');
    setTimeout(() => {
        lips.classList.remove('lips-kiss');
    }, 20);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!